# Is it possible for a user that is not the job owner to edit the job or add new steps?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, jobs

My development lead is ok to revoke the sysadmin privileges he currently has, if there is a way he can still edit/execute/enable-disable/execute application jobs.

So far, I see that with the SQLAgentOperatorRole - he can execute/stop/start jobs, view properties, enable/disable jobs and schedules, review operators, proxies, alerts and delete job history. He can create new jobs BUT he cannot edit jobs or add new steps to the job that he is not the owner of.

As far as I know, A job can be edited only by its owner or members of the sysadmin role.

I am not very clear with the proxy setup. Is there some way to handle this?

Please advise. Thank you,

Debbie

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/36007/1186

Comment: Thanks Aaron, so I presume not possible unless there is a backend way to connect as sysadmin....Thanks.